# How to check if a string has only numbers

Tags: java, string

I have this piece of code that adds a default value to a column . It works completely fine if my String is only composed by numbers, but If I have other characters that aren't numbers(example : letters,!) SQL returns an error because quoatation marks are necessary.

How can I check if the string has only numbers?

```
if(defaultValue!=null)
{
   sqlStatement+=" DEFAULT "+this.defaultValue;
}
```

Also I think I will need to escape the quotation marks right? How can I do it?

```
if (this.getSuffix() != null) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String tableName = rs.getString(3);
                    if (tableName.endsWith(this.getSuffix())) {
                        tablesFound = true;
                        if (!checkColumnsExists(s, tableName)) {
                            String sql = sqlStatement.replaceAll("name", tableName);
                            System.out.println("SQL:"+sql);
                            s.execute(sql);
                            columnsAdded = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

### Code with PreparedStatement

```
public void execute(Database database) throws CustomChangeException {

        try {
            //check if there are any errors in the changelog file
            checkArgumentsNumber();

            boolean tablesFound = false;
            boolean columnsAdded = false;
            String sqlStatement = "ALTER TABLE NAME ADD COLUMN " +this.getColumnName()+" "+this.getColumnType();

            if(notNull){
                sqlStatement+=" NOT NULL";
            }

            if(defaultValue!=null){
                sqlStatement+=" DEFAULT ?";
            }

            if (this.after != null) {
                sqlStatement += " AFTER " +this.after;
            }

            System.out.println("The statement is: "+sqlStatement);

            //get tables in the database
            JdbcConnection connection = (JdbcConnection) database.getConnection();
            DatabaseMetaData metadata;
            metadata = connection.getMetaData();
            String[] types = {"TABLE"};
            ResultSet rs = metadata.getTables(connection.getCatalog(), null, "%", types);



            //if the user chose to use a suffix
            if (this.getSuffix() != null) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String tableName = rs.getString(3);
                    if (tableName.endsWith(this.getSuffix())) {
                        tablesFound = true;
                        String addStatement=sqlStatement.replaceAll("NAME",tableName);
                        PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement(addStatement);
                        if (!checkColumnsExists(s, tableName)) {
                            if(this.defaultValue!=null){
                                System.out.println("ENTERED DEFAULT");
                                s.setString(1,this.defaultValue);
                            }
                            s.executeUpdate();
                            columnsAdded = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

           

            checkInvalidInfo(tablesFound, columnsAdded, "All the matching tables already had that column");
        } catch (InvalidArgumentsNumberException | SQLException | InvalidInfoException | DatabaseException e) {
            throw new CustomChangeException("Error enabling trigger: " + e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If quotation marks are necessary in some cases, then why not just always put them in?

Comment: Good advice. But for example if my column has type int and I sent 22 with question marks wouldn't it be a problem?

Comment: Sure.  So what you need to check is the type of the column.  Numeric columns should be without the quotes.  Columns with types like varchar should have the quotes.

Comment: How can I check if is numeric or not? With an if clause would be too long

Comment: How many different data types do you intend to cater for?

Comment: All the avaliable ones

Comment: So how is your user choosing the data type?  Are you giving them some kind of list to choose from?  And where are you getting the options in that list from?  Do you have some kind of enum for this?  If so, you should have a field in the enum that specifies how to escape the value.

Comment: Why not use a PreparedStatement? It will put the quotes and escape characters in for you.

Comment: @Dawood ibn Kareem he sends it through a XML File

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem actually if the value is numeric and I send the value with quoatation marks SQL makes the transformation itself

Comment: So it sounds like you can just always use quotation marks then.  However, this isn't the "right" solution to this problem, as a hacker who has access to your XML can really mess up your database.  You're better to use a JSON parser and put the values into a prepared statement.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how the database can be messed up? You got me curious because I never thought about it

Comment: Sure.  Click the first link in ELEVATE's answer.

Comment: And sorry, I said "JSON Parser" - of course, you want an XML Parser.

Comment: switched to PreparedStatement but now I kinda have a "problem" . Table name,column name and column type can't be passed as parameters. So I still need to concatenate the string. I still think it's better to use PrepareStatement because it escapes automatically the other parameters. How big of a vulnerability is this?

Comment: Edited my question with the new version of the code

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you should construct SQL, as it leaves you open to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

You should use JDBC `PreparedStatement` class instead. This lets you write SQL with `?` characters where you want parameters, and then set the values programmatically. It handles all the appropriate escaping to prevent SQL injection.

Here is the [Oracle Java Tutorial for Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: I edited my question with the code where I send the query. So where I have `Statement s`
should I replace by PreparedStatement? This will improve the perfomance of  my code right?

Comment: Yes, you should use a `PreparedStatement` instead. It won't improve the performance. It will make it easier for you to write and will prevent SQL injection attacks. These are a major risk if your data comes from anyone but you.

Comment: This question may sound dumb, but can I still concatenate the string based on the quantity of the parametres received ? For example I can still do that `if(defaultValue!=null), just need to replace the variables by ? ,right?

Comment: Also, one more question .Is the method commit really necessary? I do the verification if the table already has that column in case the migration wasn't completed. This way, when repeating it it will ignore the tables that already were changed

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex expression

```
String str=" your string 123";
if(str.matches("[0-9]+")){
//Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use try catch too.

```
try {
    // try to convert to number if it's integer
    Long number = Long.valueOf("number");
         
    // without question
    sqlStatement+=" DEFAULT "+ number; 

} catch (Exception ignored){
    // default value or string with question
    sqlStatement+=" DEFAULT "+this.defaultValue;
}
```

**Update**

It can be like this too.

```
Long number = null;
try {
    Long number = Long.valueOf("string number");
} catch (Exception ignored){}

// #1 if you have just number field
sqlStatement+= number != null ? number : this.defaultValue;

// #2 Or if want to use question
if(number != null)
    sqlStatement+= number       // without question
else
    sqlStatement+= " DEFAULT "  // without question
```

Comment: Though this would work, you should not encourage people to construct SQL statements in this manner. Concatenating variables to form a SQL statement risks SQL injection attacks.